# Swap two letters in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which looks like:

```
id      | flags
--------|------------
1       | ABC
2       | DEF
3       | ADF
```

And I want to swap letters A and F, to produce table:

```
id      | flags
--------|------------
1       | FBC
2       | DEA
3       | FDA
```

My intuition is to use 3 separate sql statements, with "z" as the swap character (becuase there will not be lowercase characters in flags column). So first I would `REPLACE(flags, 'A', 'z')`, then `REPLACE(flags, 'F', 'A')`, then `REPLACE(flags, 'z', 'F')`

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: The swap option is a good one IMO assuming that later on lowercase letters will be allowed, at which case your queries will all break.  You could define a UDF which would be safer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @table table
    ([id] int, [flags] varchar(3))
;

INSERT INTO @table
    ([id], [flags])
VALUES
    (1, 'ABC'),
    (2, 'DEF'),
    (3, 'ADF')
;

    declare @maxLen int, @col int=1
    select  @maxLen=max(len(flags)) from @table

    while @col < = @maxLen
    begin
        update @table
            set flags=stuff(flags,@col, 1, case SUBSTRING(flags,@col,1) 
                                            when 'A' then 'F' 
                                            when 'F' then 'A' 
                                            else SUBSTRING(flags,@col,1)  end )     
        set @col=@col+1
    end
```

http://rextester.com/OZW89662

Comment: Thank you. By any chance do you know if this can run in C# sql statements as well? No worries if it can't.

Comment: Yes, it could, maybe inside a procedure. If you have the chance to do it in c# it could be best suited there IMO.

Answer (score 1):

That depends, is your RDBMS configured to allow for case sensitivity? Some platforms, like MS Sql Server, default  to case insensitive collation during the install.

Are there any characters you know you do not use at all? You could use a special character like `!` or something similar as the temporary character instead of `z`.

I would recommend wrapping the entire update script (all 3 statements) in a transaction that you can roll back on failure / commit on success. You could also set the isolation level so there are no dirty reads of the temp flag values during the update process.

Comment: Thank you, turns out my db is case-insensitive so 'z' was a bad idea. I don't know how to wrap 3 statements into a transaction, can you give me some advice on that? I'm on Sql Management Studio (or can alternatively use C#) and the db is sql server 13.0.4001 (Microsoft SQL server 2016 I think)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can do something like this:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET flags = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(flags, 'A', '?'), 'F', 'A'), '?', 'F');
```

(i hope the order ist correct ;-) )

Replace `?` by a never used letter or sign. Some DBMS have the `TRANSLATE` function, i think Oracle und SQL Server. Maybe this is useful for you.